# Need to get location of draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a draggable div and what I want to do is be able to capture the location of the div on the page after its been dragged and the from has been submitted.

i plan to have that div render in the last location it was at when the page reloads.

My question for now is how can I capture I assume the coordinates or loacation of where the div is at after I have dragged it around the page?

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#filterItem").click(function() {
        $("#filterPanel").fadeToggle("slow", function() {
            toggleImg( 'filter' );
        });
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        toggleImg( "filter" );
        return false;
    });
    $("#filterPanel").draggable({ snap: "#filterItem" });

    $("#mgmtViewHeaders [title]").tooltip();
});

function closeDraggablePanel( panelName, topPos)
{
    $("#"+panelName+"Panel").toggle("slow", function() {
        toggleImg( 'filter' );
        // Reposition to default
        $("#"+panelName+"Panel").css( "top", topPos);
        $("#"+panelName+"Panel").css( "left", "25");
    });

}
```

HTML:

```
<c:set var="filterTop" value="150" scope="page"/>

<div id="filterDiv">
<ul class="sideMenu" style="top: ${filterTop}px;">
<li style="border-bottom: none;">
    <div id="filterItem" class="sideMenuDiv"><span><img src="../images/plus.gif" />&nbsp;Filters</span>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<%-- Y coordinate of the top edge of the filter panel. --%>
<c:set var="panelTop" value="${filterTop}" scope="page"/>

<div class="sideMenuPanel" style="display: none; width: 290px; top: ${panelTop}px;" id="filterPanel">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.position()
```

this will give u the top and left coordinates.

Comment: More specifically, `.position()` or `.offset()` depending on what your CSS is up to.